# How to create a SQL Login trigger which allows only login through application?

Tags: sql-server

How to create an login trigger which does not allow connections from ssms, but allows only login from application server?

Comment: You cannot. The only information that can be used to determine which application connected is *handed* to the server by the *client* when it connects. And the client can lie.

Comment: E.g. if you open SSMS and get the "Connect to Database Engine" dialog open, choose which server you want to connect to and then press the "Options>>" button. Switch to the "Additional Connection Parameters" tab and enter `Application Name=MySuperSecureApplication`, then press "Connect". Everything on the server side will now tell you that your connection is from `MySuperSecureApplication`, *not* SSMS.

Comment: Why blocking access from SSMS ? If you setup the security correctly for your users it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A logon trigger https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx has access to `EVENTDATA()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx which you can use to restrict logons. However, afaik this doesn't contain the Application Name (check the [schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/) for details).

And as others have said in the comments, this is easily faked anyway.

This over on DBA has a nice example of a logon trigger. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111557/56641

And remember to turn on the dedicated admin connection...